# Inputting key words and their values on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a list with words and integer values and put them in the list together. For example,
keywords:

```
rain,10
shine,5
python,10
great,1
```

Well i know how to put the words in a list, but not the values. So I did so far:

```
pyList = {'python', 'great, 'shine', rain}
```

So basically im trying to input the keywords and their values and store them in a list.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: you're looking for a dictionary. https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: let us know what do you need it for, so that we know if you need list, tuple, dictionary, or another approach...

Comment: That is not a list, it is a set. But you want to use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other answers that a dictionary is the best way to accomplish this, but if you are looking strictly for a way to put these items in a list together, you may consider creating a list of tuples.

```
a_list = [("rain", 10), ("shine", 5), ("python", 10), ("great", 1)]
```

When you want to access this data:

```
print(a_list)
```

Will output: `[('rain', 10), ('shine', 5), ('python', 10), ('great', 1)]`

To access either item independently:

```
for x, y in a_list:
    print(x)
```

Will output:

```
rain
shine
python
great
```

Of course `x` in the code above can be replaced with `y` to output the second part of the tuple instead.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary might be better than a list.

```
item_dict = {'rain': 10, 'shine': 5, 'python': 10, 'great': 1}
```

The following code

```
print(item_dict['rain'])
```

will output `10`

If you don't care what numbers they have, but just want a different one for each then you can enumerate a list and turn that into a dictionary.

```
items = ['rain','shine','python','great']
items_dict = dict(enumerate(items))
```

This will give you a dictionary with the following values

```
{0: 'rain', 1: 'shine', 2: 'python', 3: 'great'}
```

Comment: If I have 20 different items, should I still use this method and input them one by one?

Comment: Yes. If you want each to have a unique number but don't care which then you could use an enumeration. Let me know and I'll post an example.

Comment: Thanks! Very Helpful